# Bazel generate AWS lambda with python

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, bazel, bazel-rules

I am trying to create a python function that can be deployed into lambda BUT using Bazel.

I am able to create the binary file with Bazel (that runs my python code) but when I am trying to execute that binary in AWS Lambda it fails rudely.

Binary does not have the expected method signature for the lambda handler function.

This is my BUILD file:

```
py_binary(
    name = 'say_hello',
    main = 'main.py',
    srcs = ['main.py']
)
```

This is main.py:

```
def say_hello(event, context):
   print('hello')
```

How can I force Bazel to "accept" this method signature?

Comment: Why do you want to build your python program into binary?

Comment: We are trying to work with this idea of "monorepo"(https://medium.com/@Jakeherringbone/you-too-can-love-the-monorepo-d95d1d6fcebe) and using bazel to ensure that nothing will break during this.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for this and was creating like a python "bridge" that will take input values from cloudwatch rule and then execute python binary (bazel one).

So in python lambda I will have 2 files, actual binary and the bazel bridge. As lambda is always expecting that method signature.

Comment: This does not look like an Answer. Was it intended to be an edit to your question, or a Comment to another user? Non-answers are subject to deletion. To avoid this, either respond in the comments, or edit your other post, whichever is most appropriate. If it was meant to be an answer, double check guidelines in the [help center](https://StackOverflow.com/help). Otherwise, perhaps I am misunderstanding the nature of you Q or your A.

Comment: This definitely looks like an answer. Although incomplete. I'm looking into this same problem, alanmas, could you explain in more detail how that python bridge works?